# .BOT file not getting deployed to Azure Bot Service v4

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

Using Azure Bot Service with C# Bot Builder SDK v4 v4.0.7 (the GA version released September 2018).

I'm using the [BOT file](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/bot-file.md) to store configuration settings for a `GenericService` and so have changed the BOT file from the default that was provided with the Azure template.

Changes were made via [MSBOT CLI](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/add-services.md).

When running locally via the emulator, the bot code sees modified local BOT file and all is good.

However, the BOT is never deployed to Azure and therefore the Azure service does not see my changes (it is stuck with the default BOT file). I've deployed via Visual Studio publish and GitHub CI.

I had to manually upload the file using Visual Studio Cloud Explorer and the bot was then able to use the modified version and all is good.

Question is why is the BOT file not deployed with the rest of the bot code and how can I make sure it is deployed. Not sure if this is a bug or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is the fix to deploy the .bot file. In Visual Studio,

1. Right click on the .bot file
2. Click Properties
3. Under file properties, verify that "Copy to Output Directory" option says Copy Always.

Here's a screencap:
[image: Properties of .bot file]

Comment: Awesome, that works, thanks :) It should probably be the default setting for the template? Where do we provide that feedback

Comment: Great, glad that worked for you. :) I'll go ahead and get this reported for you internally. For non-ABS issues, you can file bugs at the appropriate repo listed on the [BotFramework GH](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/)

Comment: Thanks, not sure what "non-ABS issues" means but I've added it to the issues list in GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1004

Comment: ABS = Azure Bot Services. Saw your GH issue, and I got confirmation from the (ABS) team that a fix is in the works. :)